# Controlling mouse with Python Not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python Mouse Movement Doesn't Work Inside Games I'm trying to emulate mouse movement, but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried pynput, ctypes, pyautogui, win32api and pydirectinput i have tried do it on full screen and window but it doesnt seem to help eaither so any ideas? i have tried all the below code but doesnt seem it works

```
import win32api, win32con
import ctypes
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput
def click(x,y):
  win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
  win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
  win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

def moveandclick(x,y):
  ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(x, y)
  ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0,0)
  ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0,0)

time.sleep(5)
moveandclick(500,500)
winsound.Beep(200, 100)
time.sleep(2)

moveandclick(500, 1000)

winsound.Beep(200, 100)

pydirectinput.moveTo(100, 150)

pydirectinput.click()

pydirectinput.click(200, 220)
```

here is all the code i have tried

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your post